# Global Variable in Spring Integration?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have one `transformer` who's output is input for one of my `http:outbound-gateway` and the output channel of this `outbound-gateway` is input for my one of `activator`. My requirement is to get some of data from my `Transformer` to my `activator`.

Something like below.

```
 <int:transformer ref="jsonToXmlTransformer" input-channel="replyChannel" output-channel="someObj"/>

 <http:outbound-gateway 
          request-channel="someObj"  
          expected-response-type="o.s.h.ResponseEntity"
          reply-channel="replyChannel"
          url="{someurl}"
          http-method="POST"
        extract-request-payload="true">
    </http:outbound-gateway>

<int:service-activator id="expressionConverter" input-channel="replyChannel" 
   ref="lastActivator"/>
```

Dont focus on this config. I mean, I am at home and tried my best to recall my configs as office one. Nothing wrong with that. Only that I am not getting my expected data from my `transformer` to my last `activator`. Which is nothing but like an endpoint for application flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider to transfer required data in headers. Add it into headers after transformer before outbound Gateways and get it from there in the activator.